# Change any attribute of activity with NawigationDrawer fails

Tags: android, android-activity

Being total newbie in android i cannot get this:

After calling Activity with NavigationDrawer, that should change View object parameter, I get instant crash.

This is Activity code:

```
public class TrainNetwork extends Activity
        implements NavigationDrawerFragment.NavigationDrawerCallbacks {

    private DrawingView drawHere;
    public int letterID = 0;
    private NavigationDrawerFragment mNavigationDrawerFragment;
    private CharSequence mTitle;


    private void updateActivity(int position){
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "MIKE: "+position;
        int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
        toast.show();
        letterID = position;

        //drawHere.letterID = position;
        // UNCOMMENT THIS TO CRASH WHY ?

    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_train_network);

        mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
                getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
        mTitle = getTitle();

        // Set up the drawer.
        mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
                R.id.navigation_drawer,
                (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
        drawHere = (DrawingView) findViewById(R.id.drawing);
    }

    @Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1))
                .commit();
        updateActivity(position);
    }
```

And this is View class code:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.View;

public class DrawingView extends View {

    public int letterID;
    public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs){
        super(context, attrs);
        setupDrawing();
    }

    private void setupDrawing(){

    }
}
```

Do i really need fragments ? I just want to update my activity after changing in navigation drawer to one view object have diffrent backround.

Activity Layout:

```
<!-- A DrawerLayout is intended to be used as the top-level content view using match_parent for both width and height to consume the full space available. -->
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.mike.hirogana.TrainNetwork"
    android:background="@android:color/background_light">

    <!-- As the main content view, the view below consumes the entire
     space available using match_parent in both dimensions. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/background_dark"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/trainLayout"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:orientation="horizontal" >

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/new_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/start_new"
                    android:src="@drawable/new_pic"
                    android:clickable="false" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/draw_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/brush"
                    android:src="@drawable/brush" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/erase_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/erase"
                    android:src="@drawable/eraser" />

                <ImageButton
                    android:id="@+id/save_btn"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:contentDescription="@string/save"
                    android:src="@drawable/save" />
            </LinearLayout>
            <!-- Custom View -->

            <com.mike.hirogana.DrawingView
                android:id="@+id/drawing"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="#FFFFFFFF" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </FrameLayout>

    <!-- android:layout_gravity="start" tells DrawerLayout to treat
         this as a sliding drawer on the left side for left-to-right
         languages and on the right side for right-to-left languages.
         If you're not building against API 17 or higher, use
         android:layout_gravity="left" instead. -->
    <!-- The drawer is given a fixed width in dp and extends the full height of
         the container. -->
    <fragment android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/navigation_drawer_width"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:name="com.mike.hirogana.NavigationDrawerFragment"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_navigation_drawer" />


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: Did you check your Logcat to see what line you are getting the crash?

Comment: Failed to inflate
    android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #82: Error inflating class fragment

Comment: Can you show your Activity XML layout? When is that Exception occurring?

Comment: Added XML. Exception is occoring when i enter bugged activity

Comment: You just want to change a background color when you choose an item in the DrawerLayout?

Comment: Try to change `android:name="com.mike.hirogana.NavigationDrawerFragment"` to `class="com.mike.hirogana.NavigationDrawerFragment"`